# private members in Class with overload constructor C# Unit Test

Tags: c#, unit-testing, private-members, constructor-overloading

How can I get access to the private members at Unit Test? I try using PrivateObject but the overload constructor is here and I get error for _inkContainerValue. Can I get acces to the private members without using an object of class?

```
  public class Pen
   {

    private int _inkContainerValue = 1000;

    #region Constructors

    public Pen(int inkContainerValue)
    {
        this._inkContainerValue = inkContainerValue;
    }

    #endregion
    }
```

}

Comment: Generally you shouldn't be testing your private members.  If your tests need access to them then you should rethink your design.  When I don't have that luxury, though, I usually use reflection.

Comment: I know how to use reflection but I can't do that cause the constructor-overloading is here

Comment: How does accessing a field and constructor overloading is related?

Comment: I echo @SriramSakthivel.  Whichever constructor is used to create the object, the _inkContainerValue field will have the value of the inkContainerValue parameter that was passed to the called constructor.  There are three sites in the code where the value is set (not counting the redundant field initializer), but for any given object, only one of these sites is ever called.

Comment: I think that someone just forgot to declare a constructor with no parameters.As @phoog said I can't get _inkContainerValue as 1000 without declaring 1000 in constructor.Of course here is no relation when trying to get a member of the class but definitely I can not do it, because that no a constructor with no parameters. Paradox

Comment: @JonJin why do you want to get that 1000 value if there's no way any instance of the class could ever reflect that value?  What use does 1000 have to you?

Answer (score 0):

```
PrivateObject pObj = new PrivateObject(typeof(Pen));
int privateInkContainerValue = (int)pObj.GetField("_inkContainerValue");
```

Try above code to get value of _inkContainerValue field via PrivateObject class in your Unit Test.

```
// Following is overloaded version to pass value to actual Pen class's constructor.
PrivateObject pObj = new PrivateObject(typeof(Pen), new object[]{12});
int privateInkContainerValue = (int)pObj.GetField("_inkContainerValue");
```

I don't have editor with me right now. The syntax should ideally work.

Comment: The first code I used but I got error for p0bj. The second doesn't work correctly because the value of the privateInkContainerValue is 12

Comment: Could you take a look?

Comment: The 2nd works because 12 is being passed as value to your first constructor. Replace 12 with your own variable / value and you should be able to test the results.

Comment: I want to get this 1000, but not add 1000 to        new object[]{/*1000*/};

Answer (score 0):

> Can I get acces to the private members without using an object of class?

No. You have to have an instance of an object in order pull data from that object.

No offense, but your hesitance on using Reflection due to constructor overloading seems moot. It shouldn't stop you from using Reflection if you have an instance or creating one if you don't.

Here is an example using Reflection to get the value from `_ink`. It also shows you how to get an instance without using a constructor. However, keep in mind that **nothing** will be initialized. `_ink` will be `0` and not `1000` as you see it in code.

```
public class Pen
{
    int _ink = 1000;

    public Pen(int ink)
    {
        _ink = ink;
    }
}

void Test()
{
    //Create the object and check constructor set the value
    var pen = new Pen(5);
    var field = pen.GetType().GetField("_ink", BindingFlags.NonPublic|BindingFlags.Instance);

    // This should pass.
    Debug.Assert((int)field.GetValue(pen) == 5);

    // Create the pen without using constructor. 
    // No matter what, nothing is initialized meaning _ink is 0 and not 1000.
    // Hence, uninitialized.
    var uninitializedPen = (Pen)FormatterServices.GetUninitializedObject(typeof(Pen));
    field = uninitializedPen.GetType().GetField("_ink", BindingFlags.NonPublic|BindingFlags.Instance);

    //This will fail.
    Debug.Assert((int)field.GetValue(uninitializedPen) == 1000);
}
```

In order to use the `FormatterServices` class, you need to import the `System.Runtime.Serialization` namespace.

Comment: @JonJin The original code you supplied in the question? There's nothing wrong with it from what I could see. EDIT: Oh God.....

Comment: I created an instance but when I try to get value I get the "NullReference" exception

Comment: @JonJin Looking at your linked code paste, it's because you never supplied constructor arguments. It couldn't create you a `Pen` because there wasn't a matching constructor.

Comment: Thank you, the main thing that I tried. I was hoping that I can get this 1000.

Comment: this was a task for education, it seems that it's not entirely correct

Comment: Yea, not much you can do unless you can add the default constructor to that class.